# Why does my tkinter window add an extra button when I press it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter window that opens a new window when I push a button. The sub window inherits from the main tk window. However, for some reason when I press the window, the new window opens but a new button is created on the main tk window. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import tkinter, sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class MainWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Main Window")
        self.geometry("300x300")
        self.newTab = Button(text = "Open New Tab", command = self.openNewTab)
        self.newTab.pack()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)

    def openNewTab(self):
        newtab = SubWindow()

    def quit(self):
        if messagebox.askyesno("Quit", "Are you sure you want to quit?"):
            sys.exit(0)

class SubWindow(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.title("Sub Window")

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

I've tried several variations of the code but I still can't solve the problem. I'm still trying to wrap my head around class inheritance so any explanation aswell as a fix would be appreciated. Cheers.

My expectation was for the the button to open a new tab but when i use the button, the new tab does open but a new button is also added to the main window.

Comment: It is because you do not specify the parent when creating the button in `MainWindow.__init__()`, so it will always be created in the root/main window. Note that it is better to avoid creating multiple instances of `Tk`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So how would I solve that?

Comment: Note that you really don't want to be creating multiple instances of `Tk()` (or subclasses thereof) - that wastes memory, and causes a variety of problems.  Use `Toplevel()` instead for additional windows.

Comment: @jasonharper Could you explain what I should change in my code to make that happen?

Comment: Why does `SubWindow` inherit from `MainWindow`? `SubWindow` can simply inherits from `Toplevel`.